# Sorting Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,org.joda.time.DateTime]]

Tags: scala, sorting, collections, hive

I have Seq of Map in scala,  which is from hive partitions.

I need to get latest/recentbusinessdate from the below Seq of Map

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

val a = Seq(
 Map("businessdate" -> DateTime.parse("2018-03-23T00:00:00.000Z")),
 Map("businessdate" -> DateTime.parse("2018-03-24T00:00:00.000Z")),
 Map("businessdate" -> DateTime.parse("2018-03-22T00:00:00.000Z")),
 Map("businessdate" -> DateTime.parse("2018-03-21T00:00:00.000Z"))
)
```

expected output is Map with recent business date. i.e.

```
Map("businessdate" -> DateTime.parse("2018-03-24T00:00:00.000Z")
```

I tried to sort this seq of map using `sortWith` but ended up with wrong results

```
val b = a.map(x => new DateTime( x.get("businessdate").get)
  .isAfter(new DateTime( x.get("businessdate").get)))
println(b)
```

I am new to scala. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Re: `x.get("date").get` is the key not supposed to be "businessdate"?

Comment: yes by mistake i kept date its businessdate I modified.

Comment: `x.get(...).get` should give you a `DateTime`, no need to wrap it again with `new DateTime(...)`. Also you said you tried using `sortWith` but i don't see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: since its giving compile errors in the code, I dont want to confuse.... thats why  I havent updated that code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sortWith` to get the most recent Business Date:

```
val mapWithMostRecentBusinessDate = a.sortWith(
  (a, b) => a("businessdate").isAfter(b("businessdate"))
).head

println(mapWithMostRecentBusinessDate)
```

**Output**: `Map(businessdate -> 2018-03-24T00:00:00.000Z)`

Another way using `foldLeft`, likely more performant than sorting the whole `Seq` since **O(n)**:

```
val mapWithMostRecentBusinessDate = a.foldLeft(a.head)(
  (acc, b) =>
    if (b("businessdate").isAfter(acc("businessdate")))
      b
    else
      acc
)

println(mapWithMostRecentBusinessDate)
```

**Output**: `Map(businessdate -> 2018-03-24T00:00:00.000Z)`

Comment: Minor note but you can make block lambdas as arguments more readable: `a.sortWith { (a, b) => /* no braces here */ }.head`

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Indeed, updated for the `foldLeft` sample as well :)